# I am getting errors in "files under the build folder" with AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build

I am getting errors in "files under the build folder" with AndroidStudio.

The files are xml files.

I cannot fix the errors as they are in dynamically generated files.

in What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to upgrade gradle.  This forced me to change my minimum SDK version from 30 to 31.  I could build with no problem.

The change I made was the addition of 3 lines of logging.

The new .apk was 216M compared to the old at 94M

Thanks,

Jim